# What is the etymology of the shift dress?

Tags: etymology

A [shift dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemise) is a type of woman's dress. But what is the etymology of the word shift in this sense? Did shift simply mean "shirt" at some point?

The earliest quote from the OED which has shift in this meaning is:

> 1957   M. B. Picken Fashion Dict. 293/1   Shift,..loose dress hanging
>   straight from shoulders, with fulness closely belted at waistline.

Comment: Etymonline says "*probably* related to [the earlier meaning of shift, in reference to a change of clothes](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shift&allowed_in_frame=0)", but when an etymologist says "probably", my left eyebrow shifts (up). I think no one knows. The interesting thing was *shift* was a euphemistic replacement for *smock*, which was starting to feel an indelicately direct way of  mentioning underwear. In turn, as the euphemism treadmill spun though the centuries, *shift* was replaced by *chemise*.

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: It wasn't me but @DanBron and I have just done what you could have done.

Comment: @Mick  Right but an Internet search doesn't give a good answer. This is why I have asked here.  The earliest quote is so recent maybe someone alive even remembers where it came from.

Comment: I didn't close vote, since in this particular instance the obvious source has no definitive answer.

Comment: @Lembik No, shift in this sense goes back to the 1590s (which your internet search would have told you).

Comment: @DanBron Oh that's very surprising and interesting. The OED doesn't go back further than 1957 for this meaning.

Comment: @Lembik Check the link in my first comment. The OED may only be talking about *shift* after the sense .... shifted .... specifically to a *loose* undergarment, but that sense derives from the name for a tighter form. Etymologically, *shift*'s predecessor, *smock*, came from *pressing close*, and didn't get *its* sense of a looser garment til the early 1900s.

Comment: [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shift&allowed_in_frame=0) is pretty good. I always go there for any etymology questions.

Comment: @Mick Yep, see my first comment. They're not sure either.

Comment: I've always figured that the dress shifts when the wearer moves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way OED is laid out gives some idea.

> **IV.** Change, substitution, succession.
>   †**7.** Change or substitution of one thing for another of the same kind. *Obs.*
>   †**8. a.** A plurality of things of the same kind that are or may be used successively. *Obs.*
>        †**b.** A set or suit (of sails, scenes). *Obs.*
>   **9. a.** Change (of clothing); *concr.* one of several suits of clothing, or of several garments of the same kind belonging to one person. *Obs.* exc. *dial.*
>   **10. a.** A body-garment of linen, cotton, or the like; in early use applied indifferently to men's and women's underclothing; subsequently, a woman's ‘smock’ or chemise. Now chiefly *N. Amer.*

Thus it's possible to see how the original meaning of underwear came to be called a *shift* — the garment is changed regularly.

OED has a note:

> In the 17th c. *smock* began to be displaced by *shift* as a more ‘delicate’ expression; in the 19th c. the latter, from the same motive, gave place to *chemise.*

It is certainly the case that **10.b,** "A straight loose dress," only dates from 1957. But the straight, simple shape of that shift is not dissimilar to the simple shift of the fifteenth century. It's not so much a direct descendant etymologically, more named by analogy.

Answer (score 2):

My go-to source for such questions is the Online Etymological Dictionary, aka [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com).

Here's what it has to say about [*shift* in the sense of *shift dress*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shift&allowed_in_frame=0)¹.

> "body garment, underclothing," 1590s, originally used alike of men's and women's pieces, **probably** from *shift* (n.1), which was commonly used in reference to a change of clothes. In 17c., it began to be used as a euphemism for *smock*, and was itself displaced, for similar reasons of delicacy, in 19c. by *chemise*.

That *probably* makes me suspicious², but it's the best we've got. Etymonline is saying "shift dress" comes from the earlier sense of *shift* ([ibid](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shift&allowed_in_frame=0)), *to move*.

**TL;DR**: Etymonline speculates that *shift dress* comes from a metaphor of moving (*shifting*) into a new set of clothes, as in "changing underwear".

---

¹ <sub>Your OED attestation from 1950s specifically describes a *slip* as "loose", but this appears to be a newer sense of the word, which may explain the discrepancy between that citation and Etymonline's 1590s. For example, *smock*, an even older word, did not develop a sense of "loose" until the early 20th C (see below).</sub>

² <sub>The more interesting thing I took away from these etymologies is that *shift* was originally a euphemism, displacing *smock*³, which had started to feel like an indelicately direct way of talking about underwear.</sub>

<sub>In turn, as the wheels of the euphemism treadmill spun through the centuries, *shift* was itself displaced by *chemise*. Nothing like speaking French to mask indelicate details!</sub>

³ <sub>Now *smock* has [a much more satisfying etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=smock&allowed_in_frame=0). It appears to come from older words meaning *creep*, *slip*, or *press close*, as in "a tight garment one creeps or slips into".</sub>

Comment: The *sm-* in *smock* certainly suggests close contact: compare *smash, smear, smooch.*